# Trimmean in Java?

Tags: java, matlab, maven

I need a function like [Matlab's trimmean()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/trimmean.html) in Java, and I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

Anybody is aware of a ready implementation for that? (*Yes, I know I can make it in no time but I wouldn't waste time on it if someone already contributed it to the community.*)

I Googled for some alternatives but I only found partial and placeholder implementations (like [this](http://www.koders.com/java/fid2F8A2E9D978AC5567EC09F08E6D1D746B8462A02.aspx) or [this](http://www.koders.com/java/fidD9CCF80371013DA3A512BC3CB121AA8BDB5EC7A5.aspx)).

Any suggestion is more than appreciated, the best would be a Maven dependency I can go play with.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you know how to write it, and you can do so, but you can't bother to do so yourself. Instead, your question is if someone would do your work for you?

Comment: No, that wasn't what I wanted to say. I just wanted to know if there are is a specific lib that I might skipped so far. You honestly do not implement functions like sum, avg, normalize, variance and the others, right? You go and grab a bullet proof, properly tested and mature library for the task (like commons-math, don't you?). Writing functions like these are relatively easy, but testing them takes quite a lot of time. That was the reason why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the archives, I found an acceptable solution with [Colt](https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/index.html):

```
public static void trimmean(final double[] arr, final int percent) {
    if ( percent < 0 || 100 < percent ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value: " + percent);
    }

    if ( 0 == arr.length ) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    final int n = arr.length;
    final int k = Math.round(n * ( percent / 100.0 ) / 2.0); // Check overflow
    final DoubleArrayList list = new DoubleArrayList( arr );
    list.sort();
    
    return Descriptive.winsorizedMean( list, Descriptive.mean( list ), k, k );
}
```

Comment: Which library we need to include for "Descriptive" ?

Comment: The one I mentioned in the text? :-) https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This will also work.

```
public static void trimmean(ArrayList<Double> numbers, final double percentage) 
{
    if (percentage < 0 || percentage > 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int size = numbers.size();
    int removeOutlierPer = (int) (size * percentage);
    int removeOutlierCount = removeOutlierPer / 2;
    removeOutlierCount = (int) Math.floor(removeOutlierCount);
    System.out.println("Remove outliers count :: " + removeOutlierCount);

    Collections.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println("Sorted list :: " + numbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < removeOutlierCount; i++) {
        numbers.remove(i);
        numbers.remove(numbers.size() - 1);
    }

    System.out.println("After outliers removal :: " + numbers);

    double sum = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < numbers.size(); k++) {
        sum = sum + numbers.get(k);

    }

    System.out.println("Sum of outliers array :: " + sum);
    double avg = sum / numbers.size();
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
    System.out.println("After Trim Mean :: " + dec.format(avg));
}
```